# Passing a variable in PHP Global or with a function?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am bulding a small ajax chat site and am adding an image upload with msg functionality built in PHP, MySQL and jquery with ajax. My code currently will let you upload a message, I can get the image ready for upload and store URL for the database.

But I need to pass the variable to another if statement checking when the user submits a message.
I cannot seem to get it across and into my database.

Tryed global var, other stuff - think must be missing something. It is probably something obvious, excuse the code I am a graphic designer learning code!

```
$imageurl = "";


if (isset($_FILES["file"])) {

    //properties of uploaded file
    $name = $_FILES["file"] ["name"];
    $type = $_FILES["file"] ["type"];
    $size = $_FILES["file"] ["size"];
    $temp = $_FILES["file"] ["tmp_name"];
    $error = $_FILES["file"] ["error"];


    if ($error > 0) {
        die("Error uploaded file!");
    }
    else
    {

        if ($type == "video/avi" || $size > 2000000) {
            ?>
        <br>
        <p><?die("format is not allowed or size too big!");?></p>

        <?
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($temp, "msg_image/" . $name);
        }

    }
    //store url for insertation
    $imageurl = "msg_image/" . $name;

    echo '<p>You added a ' . $name . ' to your message</p>';

    return $imageurl;


}


/////need the var in here to store and update mysql database
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {

    $tostore = $imageurl;
    $username = protect($_POST['username']);
    $message = protect($_POST['message']);
    $time = time();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO messages
        (username, msgcontent, imageurl, msgtime)
        VALUES ('$username', '$message', '$tostore', $time)";


    $result = mysql_query($sql);


}
```

Comment: I've reformatted your post for readability. Next time please check this yourself.

Comment: Is this inside a function? Try leaving out the `return $imageurl;` part. I'm guessing the second `if` check is never reached. By the way: you're allowing users to overwrite each other's files: if 2 users both use "img.jpg" only the last one will be kept the way you're doing it. Also, you're only marking video files as unwanted. You'd better specify which types you actually want to *allow* instead of the other way around (like it is now).

Answer (score 3):

Your "return $imageurl" statement is stopping your script prematurely.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

i.e.

```
echo "hello";

return "world";

echo "!";
```

will only return

```
hello
```

Comment: Yeah, that return $imageurl; line is stopping it from passing through. The OP should only return if you plan on NOT saving it to the database.

Comment: thanks guys will take on board comments and the answer! I am in your debt, one day I will be posting answers myself I hope!

Comment: hey guys removed the return $imageurl and my script is still not inserting into mysql database. Strange! I could redo my code I suppose and upload image at same time as the message etc. It just bugs me when something simple is not working! Problem must be with my mysql insert into database.